# filtered_html in theme-settings.php

Tags: 7, forms

In my theme-settings.php i want to set text format to `'filtered_html'` and display in `page.tpl.php`.

I used this code to display text area:

```
$form['options']['description'] = array(
'#type'          => 'textarea',
'#title'         => t('Description'),
'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('description'),
);
```

And display it using `<?php print strip_tags(theme_get_setting('description')); ?>` in page.tpl.php

How do i set the textarea to use `'filtered_html'` format

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$form['options']['description'] = array(
'#type'          => 'text_format',
'#title'         => t('Description'),
'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('description'),
'#format'        => 'filtered_html',
);
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#text_format

Comment: im getting error Notice: Array to string conversion in include() (line 199 of F:\DEV\SITES\DEV\1se\profiles\1se\themes\1se\templates\page.tpl.php).

Comment: You're probably running into the fact that the description is being saved inside of the options array. Maybe something like `$options = theme_get_setting('options); print $options['description'];`